# Plugin cakephp-file-storage 3.0 não executa e não exibe Erro

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3

Seguindo o tutorial de instalação do **cakephp-file-storage 3.0 plugin** (que tem o objetivo de lhe dar a possibilidade de carregar e armazenar arquivos em praticamente qualquer tipo de armazenamento backend) porém não obtive sucesso no upload do arquivo (tampouco em sua alocação), não obtive nada como **Exceção Lançada** porem nada da operação de armazenamento do arquivo era executada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente temos de configurar o plugin com a configuração especifica no caso **Local Storage**:

No arquivo **bootstrap.php**

> C:\xampp\htdocs\[ProjectFolder]\config\bootstrap.php

```
StorageManager::config('Local', [
    'adapterOptions' => [TMP, true],
    'adapterClass' => '\Gaufrette\Adapter\Local',
    'class' => '\Gaufrette\Filesystem']
);
```

Ponha este bloco abaixo do bloco com os **use** (Lembre-se de adicionar o **use Burzum\FileStorage\Lib\StorageManager;** da biblioteca)

```
use Burzum\FileStorage\Lib\StorageManager;
use Cake\Cache\Cache;
use Cake\Console\ConsoleErrorHandler;
use Cake\Core\App;
use Cake\Core\Configure;
```

Esta linha pode ser ajustada a sua necessidade (Ela contem a pasta e que o arquivo será salvo).

```
'adapterOptions' => [TMP, true],
```

para (não necessáaiamente esta poderia ser outra dependendo da necessidade)

```
'adapterOptions' => [ROOT . DS . 'PicturesResources' . DS],
```

Estas são as minhas tabelas no MySql (Somente duas tabelas **products** e **medias** que armazena o caminho para uma imagem (**media_types** não é relevante ao problema))

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  product_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  quantity INT NOT NULL,
  sold INT NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(1000),
  price DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
  old_price DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
  visited INT NOT NULL,
  status INT NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE media_types (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name_media_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE medias (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  media_type_id INT NOT NULL,
  product_id INT NOT NULL,
  path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME,
  FOREIGN KEY media_type_key (media_type_id) REFERENCES media_types(id),
  FOREIGN KEY product_key (product_id) REFERENCES products(id)
);
```

Eu executei: **cake bake all products** e **cake bake all medias** e o resultado foi:

Em **ProductsTable.php**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('products');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->hasMany('Medias', [
        'className' => 'Medias',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id'
    ]);
}
```

Eu adicionei **'className' => 'Medias',** (Não me lembro se é opcional mas adicionei e não houve problemas).

O arquivo **MediasTable.php** é o mesmo gerado pela bake.

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('medias');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->belongsTo('MediaTypes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'media_type_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Products', [
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}
```

Meu **Método de upload** em **ProductsController.php**

```
 public function upload() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $mediaTypeId = 1;
        $productId = 2;
        $path = $this->request->data['Media']['file']['tmp_name'];
        $inserted = $this->Insert->insertMedia($mediaTypeId, $productId, $path);

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

        $stringSeparator = '_';
        $storeName = 'StoreGYN';
        $productName = 'TestProduct';
        $saved = $this->UploadFile->saveFileLFS($stringSeparator, $storeName,
            $productName);

        if($inserted === true && $saved === true){
            $this->Flash->set(__('Upload successful!'));
        }
    }
}
```

Eu coloquei o método responsável por **Armazenar o arquivo** em um componente (isto é opcional, porém este método deve existir)

```
public function saveFileLFS($stringSeparator, $storeName, $productName)
{
    $key = $storeName . $stringSeparator . $productName . $stringSeparator .
        $this->request->data['Media']['file']['name'];
    if(StorageManager::adapter('Local')->write($key,
        file_get_contents($this->request->data['Media']['file']['tmp_name']))){
        return true;
    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

E coloquei o método responsavel por **Salvar o caminho da imagem (no sistema de arquivos) na tabela** em um componente tabém:

```
public function insertMedia($mediaTypeId, $productId, $path)
{
    $media = TableRegistry::get('Medias')->newEntity();
    $media->media_type_id = $mediaTypeId;
    $media->product_id = $productId;
    $media->path = $path;

    if(TableRegistry::get('Medias')->save($media)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Este é o template, **Tenha muita atenção no nome dos elementos HTML**, eles tem de ser os mesmos da `$this->request->data['Media']['file']['tmp_name'];` caso contrário não conseguirá acessar os dados enviados no formulário (incluindo o arquivo).

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
    'type' => 'file'
));
echo $this->Form->file('Media.file');
echo $this->Form->error('file');
echo $this->Form->submit(__('Upload'));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

OBS: estou usando **XAMPP** e **CakePHP 3**

OBS 2: notei que muitas pessoas também não esta conseguindo usar o plugin seguindo o tutorial como esta pergunta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031237/getting-started-with-cakephp-file-storage-quickstart-guide/32038004#32038004)